# Stream - Collect by property and max

Tags: java, java-stream

## Problem Statement

Given the following class (simplified for the question):

```
public static class Match {

  private final String type;
  private final int score;

  public Match(String type, int score) {
    this.type = type;
    this.score = score;
  } 

  public String getType() {
    return type;
  }

  public int getScore() {
    return score;
  }
}
```

I have a `Stream<Match>` that contains multiple instances of the class, the same type appears multiple times, but with different scores:

```
Stream.of(new Match("A", 1), new Match("A", 2), new Match("A", 4), new Match("A", 10),
          new Match("B", 3), new Match("B", 6), new Match("B", 12),
          new Match("C", 1));
```

I now want to collect the stream so that the result is a `List<Match>` containing only the instances with the highest score of each type.

## What I tried

The following code is working, but I am not sure if it is the "optimal" solution (aside from the horrible reading and formatting):

```
.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
          Collectors.groupingBy(Match::getType, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
              Collectors.toList(),
              l -> l.stream().max(Comparator.comparing(Match::getScore)).get())), Map::values))
      .forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.getType() + ": " + m.getScore()));
```

and:

```
.collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(
          Collectors.groupingBy(Match::getType, Collectors.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(Match::getScore))), Map::values))
      .forEach(m -> m.ifPresent(ma -> System.out.println(ma.getType() + ": " + ma.getScore())));
```

Output (correct):

> A: 10
>   B: 12
>   C: 1

---

Additionally I was not able to extract a generic, static method returning a collector so that I can simply use it where I need in a way like:
  `.collect(distinctMaxByProperty(Match::getType, Match::getScore)`

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure about `B: 12` output ? I doesn't see 12 in the input :p

Comment: Ups, changed the input while writing the question. Updated!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Don’t collect into a `List`, just to extract one value, when you can collect the maximum element in the first place, e.g.

```
Map<String,Match> result =
    Stream.of(new Match("A", 1), new Match("A", 2), new Match("A", 4), new Match("A", 10),
              new Match("B", 3), new Match("B", 6), new Match("B", 12), new Match("C", 1))
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Match::getType, Collectors.collectingAndThen(
            Collectors.reducing(BinaryOperator.maxBy(
                                    Comparator.comparingInt(Match::getScore))),
            Optional::get)));
```

But whenever you encounter the necessity to extract an `Optional` in the context of `groupingBy`, it’s worth checking whether toMap` with merge function can give a simpler result:

```
Map<String,Match> result =
    Stream.of(new Match("A", 1), new Match("A", 2), new Match("A", 4), new Match("A", 10),
              new Match("B", 3), new Match("B", 6), new Match("B", 12), new Match("C", 1))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Match::getType, Function.identity(),
                 BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparingInt(Match::getScore))));
```

Once you have the `Map` you can produce your desired output via

```
result.values().forEach(m -> System.out.println(m.getType() + ": " + m.getScore()));
```

But if you don’t need the actual `Match` instances, you can do it even simpler:

```
Stream.of(new Match("A", 1), new Match("A", 2), new Match("A", 4), new Match("A", 10),
          new Match("B", 3), new Match("B", 6), new Match("B", 12), new Match("C", 1))
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Match::getType, Match::getScore, Math::max))
    .forEach((type,score) -> System.out.println(type + ": " + score));
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. As I need to keep the instances I will go with the `toMap` with merge! I just wrapped it with another `Collectors.collectingAndThen([...], Map::values)`

Answer (score 4):

I have two methods for you.

### First Method: Collectors.toMap()

A possible implementation is to use `Collectors.toMap()` to answers your problem.

```
stream.collect(Collectors.toMap(Match::getType, Match::getScore, Math::max));
```

And if you prefer to get a `List<Match>()`, you can remap the result

```
stream
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(Match::getType, Match::getScore, Math::max))
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    .map(e -> new Match(e.getKey(), e.getValue()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

---

### Second Method: Custom Collector

Like you say in your question, it is possible to extract this logic in a custom collector. You can do it like this:

```
public class MaxMatch implements Collector<Match, Map<String, Integer>, List<Match>> {
    @Override
    public Supplier<Map<String, Integer>> supplier() {
        return HashMap::new;
    }

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<Map<String, Integer>, Match> accumulator() {
        return (map, match) -> {
            Integer score = match.getScore();
            if(map.containsKey(match.getType())) {
                score = Math.max(score, map.get(match.getType()));
            }
            map.put(match.getType(), score);
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<Map<String, Integer>> combiner() {
        return (mapA, mapB) -> {
            mapA.forEach((k, v) -> {
                if(mapB.containsKey(k)) { mapB.put(k, Math.max(v, mapB.get(k))); }
                else { mapB.put(k, v); }
            });
            return mapB;
        };
    }

    @Override
    public Function<Map<String, Integer>, List<Match>> finisher() {
        return (map) -> map.entrySet().stream().map(e -> new Match(e.getKey(), e.getValue())).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.emptySet();
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
stream.collect(new MaxMatch());
```

Hope this help you :)

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. Unfortunately it is important to keep the instances and not recreate them in my case. The `Match` class was just for the example.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a `TreeMap` for this :

**UPDATE**

```
List<Match> matchStream1 = matchStream.
            collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Match::getType,
                    Collectors.toCollection(() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Match::getScore)))))
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(TreeSet::last)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

In case your `Match` class implements `Comparable`. You can simplify this:

```
() -> new TreeSet<>(Comparator.comparing(Match::getScore))
```

to this:

```
TreeSet::new
```

Comment: Executing your code on the example stream I provided I will only get: `"B: 12"`. I added the expected output to the question.